# Javascript function arguments has to be a string?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript so I'm not sure why it's behaving like this.

I have a clock function:

```
function updateClock()
{
var currentTime = new Date();

var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();
var currentMilliseconds = currentTime.getMilliseconds();

// Pad the minutes and seconds with leading zeros, if required
currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;

// Choose either "AM" or "PM" as appropriate
var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";

// Convert the hours component to 12-hour format if needed
currentHours = ( currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;

// Convert an hours component of "0" to "12"
currentHours = ( currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;

// Update the time display
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;
}
```

which is in a separate `clock.js` file.  I include that file in the head.

I place this under the `clock div`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval("updateClock()", 1000);
</script>
```

And it works.  But if I change it to `setInterval(updateClock(), 1000);`, it won't work.  I spent a while trying to figure out why the function only executed once until I found out I needed to put quotes around the function call.

Coming from different languages background, I don't know why you need to put quotes around it? It looks like I'm passing a string `"updateClock()"` to the function instead of another function.  I see other people's code where they just define the whole function as a parameter such as `setInterval(function(){ ... }, 1000)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`setInterval()` takes as its first argument

1. A string of code to be evaluated (`'updateClock()'`)  - This is not the preferred use, as it relies on `eval()`.  The string is evaluated as JavaScript code.
2. A pointer to a function (`updateClock`) - Note the lack of parens. In JavaScript, a defined function can be referenced, *not called*, by using its name without `()`.  The pointer can also be an anonymous function as in `setInterval(function(){stuff...}, time)`, which is effectively the same thing as a reference to a defined function -- both point to a function's location in memory, whether or not it has a name.

So in your case, the preferred usage would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
</script>
```

Same goes for its cousin `setTimeout()`.

Comment: +1 Nice description of the problem rather than only providing the correct code.

Comment: @jfriend00 _Answers_ are different from _solutions_. I'm careful to provide _answers_. :)

Comment: So only for specific functions, I can reference a function without the `()`? But otherwise I still use `()` to make function calls?

Comment: I would add that the parameters are evaluated before being passed, so when you say `setTimeout(updateClock(), 1000)`, `updateClock` is called once, and *the return value* is passed to `setInterval`.

Comment: @Ryder - if you want to execute the function now, you put parens on the end. `updateClock()` executes it right now.  If you want to pass a reference to the function to some other function so it can call it later, you do not use the parens `setTimeout(updateClock, 1000)`.

Comment: @Ryder you can reference any function just like any other variable, to pass it as an argument to another function for example- and use `()` to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
setInterval( updateClock, 1000);
```

Comment: I didn't something like that would work.  I assumed that calling a function needed `()` at the end.

Comment: Well you are telling setTimeout "this is the function I want you to call" whereas the parenthesis mean "run this function now and pass the result to the setTimeout to run when it's read. If the result is not a function, setTimeout won't be able to do anything with it.